# python dict not displayed in order

Tags: python

Could you please tell me whats the difference between python dict on below two cases. First one prints the data in correct order but on second iteration P6 take precedence over P5. What will be the reason?

```
>>> a=["P3", "P4"]
>>> devices_by_dc = {}
>>> for b in a:
...   devices_by_dc[b] = {}
>>> print devices_by_dc
{'P3': {}, 'P4': {}}


>>> a=["P5", "P6"]
>>> devices_by_dc = {}
>>> for b in a:
...   devices_by_dc[b] = {}
{'P6': {}, 'P5': {}}
```

Comment: Please see OrderedDict in collections module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, dictionaries are not ordered, they are a set-like objects. Therefore the order of printing it is completely random.

Consider `dict.keys()`. That is a set. So basically when you do

```
print(dict)
```

what actually happens is

```
for key in dict.keys():
    str_out = ' \'{0}\': {1},'.format(key, dict[key]
print '{{ {0} }}'.format(str_out[:-1])
```

And since `dict.keys()` is a set, the order of selecting keys is random.

If you want to introduce order into dictionary, then instead of `dict` use `collections.OrderedDict` as suggested in the comment to the question. Don't forget to `import collections`.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python are not ordered by default. You can use an `OrderedDict` instead.

```
import collections

devices_by_dc = collections.OrderedDict()
for b in a:
    devices_by_dc[b] = {}
```